# Updating Laravel 5.6 to Laravel 8 app()->call

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am migrating my project from Laravel 5.7 to Laravel 8. Inside my controller called ProductController.php, I make another call to another controller: AjaxController.php. Okay, I know it's not good practice to do this, but I want to keep it. The problem is that the code worked well in Laravel 5.7.

```php
$p = array('article_id' => $id_param);

$quantity_discounts = app()
    ->call('App\Http\Controllers\AjaxController@getQuantityDiscounts', 
    [$p])->getData();
```

In Laravel 8, I get the following error.

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException Unable to
> resolve dependency [Parameter #0 [  $params ]] in class
> App\Http\Controllers\AjaxController

Why does this happen? I leave here below the code of my AjaxController.php:

```php
class AjaxController extends Controller
{
    private $accesible_methods = array(
        'getQuantityDiscounts',
    );

    public function get(Request $request, $action)
    {
        if (is_callable(array($this, $action)) && in_array($action, $this->accesible_methods))
            return $this->{$action}($request->all());
    }

    public function post(Request $request, $action)
    {
        if (is_callable(array($this, $action)) && in_array($action, $this->accesible_methods))
            return $this->{$action}($request->all());
    }

    public function getQuantityDiscounts($params)
    {
        try {
            $article = FotiArticle::get($params['article_id'], array(
                'fields' => 'article_id,prices,price_pvp,quantity',
                'expand' => 'prices',
                'round_decimals' => $params['round_decimals'] ?? true
            ));

            foreach ($article->prices as &$scaled_price) {
                $discount_data = Helpers::getDiscountPriceIfApplies($article->article_id, $article->price_pvp, $scaled_price->price_pvp);
                $scaled_price->price_pvp = $scaled_price->price_pvp;
                $scaled_price->price_pvp_with_discount = $discount_data->price_with_discount ?? $scaled_price->price_pvp;
            }

            $result = $article->prices;
        } catch (FotiApiException $e) {
            $result = [
                'error' => array(
                    'description' => $e->getMessage() . '. Line:' . $e->getLine()
                )
            ];
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $result = [
                'error' => array(
                    'description' => $e->getMessage() . '. Line:' . $e->getLine()
                )
            ];
        }

        return response()->json($result);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can recommend you read the upgrade guides from https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade and work your way through the versions. Thats the best way imo.

Comment: That comment is very generic. I've simply created a new Laravel 8 project and I'm moving the files from the old project to the new one. I don't get a response to this in the documents.

Comment: did you try passing that array as an associative array so it knows what parameter you are trying to pass?  `['params' => $p]`

Answer (score 0):

From design perspective, why not extract `getQuantityDiscounts` in a trait and then use the trait in both controllers.

This way it also makes the code less dependent/brittle on/due to changes in framework methods/signatures.

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use FotiApi,FuLoc, FotiArticle, FotiCart, Input;
use App\Helpers;


trait CalulatesQuantityDiscount
{
      

    public function getQuantityDiscounts($params)
    {
        
        try
        {
            $article = FotiArticle::get($params['article_id'],array(
                'fields'     =>  'article_id,prices,price_pvp,quantity',
                'expand'     => 'prices',
                'round_decimals' => $params['round_decimals'] ?? true
          ));
        
            foreach($article->prices as &$scaled_price) 
            {
                $discount_data = Helpers::getDiscountPriceIfApplies($article->article_id, $article->price_pvp, $scaled_price->price_pvp);
                $scaled_price->price_pvp = $scaled_price->price_pvp;
                $scaled_price->price_pvp_with_discount  = $discount_data->price_with_discount ?? $scaled_price->price_pvp;
            }

            $result = $article->prices;

        }
        catch(FotiApiException $e)
        {

            $result = [
                'error' => array(
                    'description' => $e->getMessage().'. Line:'.$e->getLine()
                )
            ];
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            $result = [
                'error' => array(
                    'description' => $e->getMessage().'. Line:'.$e->getLine()
                )
            ];
        }       

        return response()->json($result);
    }
}
```

Then use trait in both controllers

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use FotiApi,FuLoc, FotiArticle, FotiCart, Input;
use Exception, LogicException, Foticos\FotiApiClient\FotiApiException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Helpers;

class AjaxController extends Controller
{
    use CalculatesQuantityDiscount;

    /* Inicio */

    private $accesible_methods = array(                         
        
        'getQuantityDiscounts',
    );

    public function get(Request $request, $action)
    {       
        if (is_callable(array($this,$action)) && in_array($action,$this->accesible_methods))
            return $this->{$action}($request->all());
    }

    public function post(Request $request, $action)
    {       
        if (is_callable(array($this,$action)) && in_array($action,$this->accesible_methods))
            return $this->{$action}($request->all());
    }
}
```

```php
class OtherController extends Controller
{
    use CalculatesQuantityDiscount;

    // controller code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing
`app()->call($controller . '@' . $method, [$id]);`
to
`app()->call($controller . '@' . $method, ['id' => $id]);`
resolves the issue.